# Accessing <iframe> upon an event in the iframe - with a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Using an extension, I'd like to measure the offset of an iframe (relative to the top window) when a specific event happens in it.
This includes iframes of different origins.

It seems to require two things:

1. catching the event in the iframe's own content-document
2. finding the iframe's corresponding DOM element (`<iframe>`) in its parent window and measuring its offset

I can run a content-script in all iframes which would catch the specific event, but I fail to identify an iframe's corresponding DOM element in iframes with different origins, since in those cases I'm denied access to 'window.frameElement'.

Any ideas?
I could perhaps look for an  element with an 'src' attribute corresponding to 'window.location.href' as seen in the context of the iframe's content-script, but 'window.location.href' wouldn't be a unique identifier... or would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the following approach:

1. Use the `"all_frames":true` flag of `"content_scripts"` in the manifest file to execute the content script in all frames.
2. Bind a `message` event listener which performs the logic.
3. Bind an event listener for the trigger in question.
4. Whenever the event in step 3 is fired, use `if (top === window)` to determine whether the we're inside the top window.

   - If yes, we're done.
   - If not, use `parent.postMessage({currentTotal: ... }, '*');` to pass data to the parent frame. The `message` event listener from step two should detect this event, process it, and repeat step three.

I've explained how to approach the problem. One more useful code snippet: You need to identify the source frame. To achieve that, we use the `contentWindow` property of an `<iframe>` object for comparison with the `source` property of the event object:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (top === window) {
        // do something with e.data
    } else {
        var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for (var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++) {
            if (iframes[i].contentWindow === event.source) {
                // Found frame; measure offset, and pass data to parent frame
                var data = e.data;
                e.data += iframes[i].getBoundingClientRect().top; // example
                parent.postMessage({currentTotal: data}, '*');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

With these hints you should be able to write the full code yourself. To measure offsets, use the [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method. For completeness, I also include links to other relevant documentation: [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage), [Content scripts (manifest)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration).

Comment: The problem is that parent is undefined in the content script context for an iframe with different origin as the parent.

Comment: @rsanchez Inject your script, so that it runs in the context of the page. For more details on injecting, see [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)

Comment: The chrome inspector is useful as it allows running code in either context: all of 'top', 'parent' and 'iframes[i].contentWindow' are undefined in extension context, and throw 'unsafe javascript...' in page context - when dealing with iframes with different origins.

Comment: @afters `iframes[i].contentWindow` can be used in strict comparisons without throwing any errors. As I said in my previous comment, inject the code in the page. I have already created a detailled answer on doing that (see link in previous comment), so I'm not going to repeat that in my answer. If you get stuck trying, reply back and explain what you've tried without luck.

Comment: Also, can 'window.postMessage' be used to send messages between content-scripts, or should the extensions' message passing be used?

Comment: @afters Content scripts can use `postMessage` and receive `message` events from the page, so you do not need to use `chrome.extension.sendMessage`/`onMessage`. In your case, `postMessage` is the best solution, because you also need to know the source of a message.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. That indeed answers my question. I am somewhat concerned about foreign scripts (running in different iframes in the hierarchy) being able to listen-in and know when an event happens in an inner iframe. Any way to mitigate it that you can think of?

Comment: Will do, Rob. I added a question to my last comment, just fyi.

Comment: There's no way to prevent others from reading this message. Poorly coded pages could even break by the code, because they're receiving an unexpected message event.

Comment: @RowW not true, you can set a receiving origin parameter, page must match to receive your message.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but the `iframes[i].contentWindow === event.source` is failing in FF (it matches every iframe). I was wondering if you've come across this and found a fix? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20250774/1750282

Comment: @RandyHall In response to your first comment: The `origin` parameter won't be of much use if you are trying to send a message from a content script to a content script hosted in another page. This "another page" can read the message that is intended for your content script. (NOTE: In case you didn't notice: This Q&A is about Chrome extensions)